# Accepted, but wrong answer - question marked as duplicate to the wrong answer

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, moderators

There is an [question and an accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176371/can-i-delete-private-var-folders-bf).

I do not want to dig into the technical details (meta is not the right place) - in short:

It is possible to prove that the **accepted answer is wrong**. Since I know that the original response is bad - [I asked an another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177780/run-level-shell-scripts-cleaning-var-folders-when-changing-run-levels?noredirect=1#comment210435_177780) (now deleted) what (partially) is an variant to the original - what *could be correct* - but I'm not sure.

@Patrik closed it as a duplicate.

What to do when a question is marked as a duplicate (and commented as unclear and opinion based), but

- The answer to the original question is entirely wrong
- the new question is **not an exact** duplicate - but it is new approach  what could be right
- The question doesn't contains anything for what could't be exists unambiguous and clear answer - i.e. nothing is "opinion based"
- And trying solve the problem (with respect to possible complications)
- but the moderator closes it :(

[I could call myself as StackOverflow veteran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632407/jm666) trusted user with 23k reputation and ability closing `bash` questions by one click. But I trying to be pretty sure that I did not make hasty conclusions, and when I made a mistake [what also happens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29112449/632407), quickly reopening the question again.

Also trying edit the question if I can improve it to be better instead of the "blind close". (unfortunately, English isn't my primary language, so mainly doing only code-snipets improving).

For the "disputable" moderator decisions are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158877/163674) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253129/632407) some good answers (to bad questions) - so, asking in the apple's meta - maybe the Think Different idea applies here too. ;)

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: I don't have time to dig into the links, but when there is a wrong answer the best option is to provide the correct answer - possibly having a comment and or sidebar explaining in what circumstances another answer (link to it) is wrong. Asking a new question seems less likely to help the site until other avenues are exhausted.

Comment: @bmike - agree. Unfortunately i don't know the good answer (only know than the original is wrong). Therefore asked the **variant** question - what could be ok - but got closed. Got closed one question - nothing horrible happens - only want point to the fact than moderators really should have "sensitive finger on the gun trigger" - and think twice before applies an "diamod close". :)

Comment: I think a comment, with some details, is warranted on the accepted answer in this case. Especially since, given the nature of the question, relying on that answer could prove fairly bad if the user isn't running something like Time Machine to be able to recover from the deletion.

Comment: @jm666 why not undelete your second question and let's edit the question since you're quite convinced there's room for a new situation / clarity - closing it as dupe helps when multiple search terms get you to the correct place. Also bounties work well for getting an updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You initially asked

> It is safe delete everything bellow /private/var/folders/?
>
> Another (more important) question - has the OS X something as rc.6, e.g. an shell script what is running when changing the run level to 6 - e.g. at every reboot? (Or rc.0 at every boot), to where I could add the rm?
>
> Is safe clean the /var/folders/* at every reboot? (asking because i could imagine than some update utility could use it...).

There are several problems with this question which may have lead to it being put on hold in the next hours/days:

- there are (at least) two questions at once, leading to a close due to being too broad or unclear what you are asking
- part of the question have come up before (and being answered already), leading to a close as a duplicate

I've decided to follow up on the second option (as there was no reference at all to that question in your text), I also recommended to ask a new question to cover the "can I safely clean the folders on reboot".

If you think the answer to the original question is wrong, the best course of action would be to add a comment to that answer (you have more than enough reputation for this), post a new answer on your own or do both.

Comment: I checked your answers. You're an good unix-guru with a deep knowledge of the system, bash and like - so - i'm **pretty sure** that you know yourself, than the answer **is wrong**. Therefore I was surprised by your close. As I told above - nothing horrible happens - maybe next time, instead of the close vote - you could EDIT the question - to be better. Thank you for answer. accept - case closed. :)

Comment: The question was put *on hold* due to the reasons outlined above, *not* due to any technical merits (or lack thereof) of either the question or the existing answer to a related question. Usually editing an unclear question to improve it is a community effort.